# Centralized System for Managing Data Ingest/Output

Tags: linux, file-transfer

The company I work for produces software that takes in Gigabytes of data a day, and outputs (lesser amounts of) Gigs a day. We have a significant infrastructure for managing data flow, and by significant I mean significantly bad. When we require a new type of data in our software, we develop a script for pulling data from an HTTP or FTP source, drop it on a server, and go. There are often complaints of over/under-utilization across most of our servers, but we have no good way for managing the balance of resources spent retrieving / writing out data.

Is there a software package that is designed to manage data transfer externally (retrieval) as well as passing it around from server-to-server inside our network?

I'm looking for something that offers;

- A common base for simplifying the design of download scripts.
- A logging/monitoring framework for knowing what's going on, what may have not been retrieved, etc. (Bonus points if the monitoring aspect can integrate into NAGIOS.)
- A single location for viewing the status of download tasks, etc. (i.e. A Dashboard)
- An implementation meant to be run across multiple servers, with ultimately what amounts to multiple server download slaves.
- Simplicity (relatively speaking). Again, we're trying to get off of a nightmare infrastructure.

Comment: We have several homegrown tools to do this sort of thing. Some are java, some are perl, some are sh, some are Windows .NET apps. One team even built a tracker and made a spiffy AJAX frontend for theirs to find lost/stranded. Of course, it only works for their tool, not any of the other ones we have in-house.

Comment: Some advice - use an existing log framework, like log4j, that has levels (debug, info, warn, error). For tracking, you need to assign a GUID or something as soon as it is seen by your tools. Something like Java can be run everywhere : windows, unix, etc. Run it with a server and client instances, so you can start a new source/destination without having to take down the whole copy process.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, it reminded me that I didn't specify OS. We're using CentOS 5 pretty much across the board, so portability (regarding OS) is irrelevant. Sounds like you're an advocate for "rolling your own". It's certainly quite possible for me/us too, I just don't want to :).

Comment: I wish there was open source software for th

Comment: I'm not necessarily an advocate of "DIY", it's just pretty common for your case, in my experience. As @zerolagtime said below, this is something that workflow software can do, and it's usually hella expensive. Lombardi (bought by IBM) does stuff like this. I have also seen scheduling software (the big stuff, like Espresso) used for filecopies. You can be sure those packages have logging, retries, even job distribution. And $$$$$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OASIS group published a standard language for defining "business processes" called BPEL (Business Process Execution Language).  We have used the expensive, commercial version for a few years for the very reasons you listed: maintainability, scalability, extensibility, verifiability.  Fortunately for you, many projects have taken these tasks on.  Some open-source versions are at [freshmeat.net](http://freshmeat.net/search?q=bpel&submit=Search).  Us mere mortals call this "workflow software."  One package that caught my eye was [Orchestra](http://freshmeat.net/projects/orchestra) as it is both LGPL and comes with commercial support options.  Given that it is a critical business process, you may want *some* level of support, or at least contribute back any changes to the community.

Fortunately for you, many, many others have blazed this trail.  It's just a matter of following in a way that is politically correct in your organization.  I recommend a private prototype and a demonstration to get senior management to buy in to a larger, business-relevant test.  Get the boss to buy-in fairly early and you might be able to change this core business practice.

Comment: Yikes. At first I thought this was just modeling/UML, a glorified "this is the flow, let's put it into practice this way" chart, but I dove in and started to understand more about what's going on. This is most certainly a brand new direction for me, and I admit it seems a bit overkill for what I expected to be relatively common, but couldn't find the words for it. Thanks for your help. [edit] I really wish I would stop pressing enter in comments. These aren't the Line Breaks you're looking for.